# optimize the volume of a box where the sum of the h*d*w is the only known variable

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm currently stuck with the following optimization excercice:

> Consider a box such that sum of its sides is $210$. Find the maximum
>   volume that the box can have.

Here are my current thoughts:

$$h = 210 - d - w$$

then I would put it into the volume formula:

$$V = (210 - d - w)  d  w $$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$V = 210dw - d^2w - dw^2.$$

Here, how I got the first derivative:

$$f'(d) = 210w - w^2 - dw$$

and to find the maximum value I set it equal to $0$.

$$0 = 210w - w^2 - dw$$
dividing by $w$, I got
$$0 = 210 - w - d.$$

How do I proceed from here or did I go wrong?

Comment: you should take the partial derivative respect to two variables

Comment: @mathlove thanks for noticing fixed it

Comment: @Essam what do you mean? w = 210 - d and d = 210 - w?

or 

f(w)' = 210*d-d^2-d*w^2

0 = 210*d-d^2-d*w^2 divide by d
0 = 210-d-w^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V=210dw-d^2w-dw^2$$
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial w}=210d-d^2-2dw=0$$
$$210-d-2w=0$$
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial d}=210w-2dw-w^2=0$$
$$210-2d-w=0$$

solve the two simultaneous equations to find that
$$d=70$$
$$w=70$$
then
$$h=70$$
after that you should check if these values give you a maximum volume as follow:

find the follwing derivatives at $d=70$ and $w=70$ 
$$\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial w^2}$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial d^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial w \partial d}$$

now the following condition gives you the maximum voulme

$$\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial w^2}*\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial d^2}-(\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial w \partial d})^2>0$$
$$\frac{\partial^2V }{\partial w^2}<0$$

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the hint I needed

Comment: @Gildraths, you are welcome

Answer (score 4):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$ (hdw)^{1/3}\leq\frac{h+d+w}{3}=70, $$
hence the volume is at most $70^3$ and it is attained when the box is a cube.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your solution. I "know" that a cube is the optimal form for a volume. However I should find it with the first deriative to find the solution. 

How could I achieve that? Or did I miss something in the answer? Sorry I'm struggling with optimization a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can do this as follows, which is clunky, but which I used to use a bit.

Fix $H$ so that you want to maximise $D\times W=P$ subject to $D+W=210-H=S$

Now note that $$S^2=(D+W)^2\ge (D+W)^2-(D-W)^2=4DW=4P$$

So that $P$ is greatest when $D=W$.

Since $H$ is not distinguished in any way, if any pair of $H, D, W$ are not equal to each other then the product can be increased by keeping the third of them fixed and making the others equal. The only circumstance in which there is no possible increase is $H=D=W$.